# Can a projectile moving at supersonic velocities leave a silhouette in whatever it hits?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, collision

I was recently reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154286/action-and-reaction-time-lag), and Floris's answer confirmed my knowledge that the information of an collision travels at the speed of sound. While I was thinking about that, my mind wandered and I began thinking of "Calvin & Hobbes" comics.

My question arises when you think of the strips where Calvin falls, and ends up in a body-shaped hole. ***If an object was moving faster than the speed of sound, could it put an outline in whatever it hit?*** (Provided the substance was soft enough. Say, drywall.)

If a person hit a sheet of drywall moving fast enough so that neither object had time for the information of the impact to propagate through it, could you have a person-shaped hole in a piece of drywall? (Retaining detail, such as the outline of any outstretched fingers. For the sake of simplicity, we can assume this occurs in a vacuum so that we don't have to worry about the cone of pressurized air that you get at supersonic velocities.)

Comment: Seems related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136071/can-you-punch-a-hole-in-an-a4-sheet-of-paper-with-your-hand

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, I am assuming the drywall is being supported, and I want to know if you can put a shaped hole in it. (not just a plain hole)

Comment: Also seems related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hinsdale_APA-120_-_kamikaze.jpg

Comment: @KyleKanos Interesting picture. Did I see the shape of the wings on the side of the ship?

Comment: Looks that way to me.